# Importing from lower level of node package

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I have a node package (lets call it `my-package`) that currently looks like the following

```
src/
  index.js
  generators/
    generate-stuff.js
```

`index.js` looks like the following

```
module.exports={
      "some": {
          "json": "objects",
          ...
      },
      "other": {
          "json": "things",
          ...
      }
};
```

Now I can import this file very easily in other packages by doing the following

```
const myPackage = require('my-package');
```

And `myPackage` will have the contents of that JSON you see above

However what I really want to import is a function that exists in `generate-stuff.js` (The structure of this package is inherited and I cannot easily change it)

That file looks like the following

```
module.exports = { functionIWantToExport(input1, input2){
        return {
            // do stuff with said inputs
        };
    }
}
```

However when I do something like

```
const functionIWant = require('my-package/generators/generate-stuff');
```

I get the following failure.

```
Cannot find module 'my-package/generators/generate-stuff'
```

Is there any way I can pull out the function I need from this package?

I can see in my `node_modules` that the `module.exports` is on the file I need

Comment: What "failure" do you get? On first glance, things seem alright, though you may want to use a default export or the function or do something like `const {functionIWant} = require(...)` to unpack it from the exports object.

Comment: @AKX sorry should have added my error, I have edited the question to do

Answer (score 0):

So was able to figure out the source of my problem.  And it has do with the `main` in `package.json`

In my `package.json` there is the following

```
"main": "src/index.js"
```

So that's why just doing `require('my-package');` works.  But if I want to use the relative path it's still from above the src folder, so what I really need is

```
const functionIWant = require('my-package/src/generators/generate-stuff');
```

Doing this resolved my issue